# How do you add slide presenter notes in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice, presentation

How do you add slide presenter notes in LibreOffice Impress?

I need to add a transcript to read for each slide during my presentation. (It should also serve as notes for the student if viewing the presentation file later.)

Answer (score 32):

Click View > Notes in the menu bar (move the cursor to the top of the screen to reveal the menu bar). At first it looks like only something to be displayed if printing the slides, but after adding notes in the text section, press F5 to start the presentation, click the 'Notes' icon at the bottom of the presenter view, and you'll find the notes there to be read during the presentation.

Comment: @LostCrotchet not to start a debate in here or something, but you're using free open-source software that's built by amazing people (I'm not one of them). As it applies to any OSS you can gladly provide constructive criticism/feedback, but your comment neither adds something to the topic nor does it suggest a fix. it doesn't fit your use-case? you have some ideas to make it better? then suggest them to the developers, but "It sucks!" helps no one.

Comment: Is there a way to display the notes more like a toolbar underneath the regular slide editing view, much like how google docs does it?